# com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Illegal character (CTRL-CHAR, code 5): only regular white space (\r, \n, \t) is allowed between tokens

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

the token seems to be generating fine as i check it with jwt.io and it seems good to go. But when i try to access any endpoint after authorization, it says 403 forbidden in postman and when i check the console, it says malformed token exception. I tried everything but it doesn't seem to go away. I want to do a role based authorization so i try to add the Role tag in claims to retrieve from the token and authorize. but it is not working.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Below is the codebase for the reference.
[![console output.

```
package com.employeedirectory.Employee.Service;

import com.employeedirectory.UserDetails.UserDetailsEntity.UserInfo;
import com.employeedirectory.UserDetails.UserDetailsRepository.UserInfoRepository;
import com.employeedirectory.UserDetails.UserDetailsService.UserInfoUserDetails;
import io.jsonwebtoken.*;
import io.jsonwebtoken.impl.TextCodec;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.Function;

@Component
public class JwtService {
    private String secret;
    private int jwtExpirationInMs;

    @Autowired
    UserInfoRepository userInfoRepository;

    @Value("${jwt.secret}")
    public void setSecret(String secret){
        this.secret = secret;
    }

    @Value("${jwt.jwtExpirationInMs}")
    public void setJwtExpirationInMs(int jwtExpirationInMs){
        this.jwtExpirationInMs=jwtExpirationInMs;
    }

    public String extractUsername(String token) {
        return extractClaim(token, Claims::getSubject);
    }

    public Date extractExpiration(String token) {
        return extractClaim(token, Claims::getExpiration);
    }

    public <T> T extractClaim(String token, Function<Claims, T> claimsResolver) {
        final Claims claims = extractAllClaims(token);
        return claimsResolver.apply(claims);
    }

    private Claims extractAllClaims(String token) {
        return Jwts.parser()
                .setSigningKey(secret)
                .parseClaimsJws(token)
                .getBody();
    }

    private Boolean isTokenExpired(String token) {
        return extractExpiration(token).before(new Date());
    }

    public Boolean validateToken(String token, UserDetails userDetails) {
            final String username = extractUsername(token);
            return (username.equals(userDetails.getUsername()) && !isTokenExpired(token));
    }


    public String generateToken(UserDetails userDetails) {

        Optional<UserInfo> userInfo = userInfoRepository.findByName(userDetails.getUsername());
        String userEmail = userInfo.get().getEmail();
        Map<String,Object> claims=new HashMap<>();
        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> roles = userDetails.getAuthorities();
            claims.put("Email",userEmail);
            if (roles.contains(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ADMIN")) || roles.contains(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("admin"))){
                claims.put("Role","ADMIN");
            }
            if (roles.contains(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER")) || roles.contains(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("user"))){
                claims.put("Role","USER");
            }
        return createToken(claims,userDetails.getUsername());
    }

    private String createToken(Map<String, Object> claims, String userName){
        return Jwts.builder()
                    .setClaims(claims)
                    .setSubject(userName)
                    .setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                    .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()+jwtExpirationInMs))
                    .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, TextCodec.BASE64.decode(secret)).compact();
    }
}
```

](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqucJ.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqucJ.png)

```
package com.employeedirectory.Employee.Filter;

import com.employeedirectory.Employee.Service.JwtService;
import com.employeedirectory.UserDetails.UserDetailsService.UserInfoUserDetailsService;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;
import java.io.IOException;

@Component
public class JwtAuthFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private String secret;

    @Value("${jwt.secret}")
    public void setSecret(String secret){
        this.secret = secret;
    }

    @Autowired
    private JwtService jwtService;

    @Autowired
    private UserInfoUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        String token = null;
        String username = null;
        String role = null;

        if (authHeader != null && authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            System.out.println("Inside doFilterInternal method.");
            token = authHeader.substring(7);
            username = jwtService.extractUsername(token);
            Claims claims = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secret).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
            role = claims.get("Role").toString();
        }

        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
            if (jwtService.validateToken(token, userDetails)) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                authToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);
            }
            request.setAttribute("Role",role);
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

```
package com.employeedirectory.Employee.Config;

import com.employeedirectory.Employee.Filter.JwtAuthFilter;
import com.employeedirectory.UserDetails.UserDetailsService.UserInfoUserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserInfoUserDetailsService userInfoUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    JwtAuthFilter jwtAuthFilter;

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService(){
        return new UserInfoUserDetailsService();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
//        http.csrf().disable()
//                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/","/newUser","/authenticate").permitAll()
//                .and()
//                .authorizeRequests()
//                .antMatchers("/api/v1/**").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN","admin","USER","user").anyRequest().authenticated().
//                and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        http.csrf().disable().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/","/authenticate","/newUser").permitAll()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("api/v1/**").access("hasAnyRole('ADMIN','USER')")
                .antMatchers("api/v2/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(){
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

```
package com.employeedirectory.UserDetails.UserDetailsService;

import com.employeedirectory.UserDetails.UserDetailsEntity.UserInfo;
import com.employeedirectory.UserDetails.UserDetailsRepository.UserInfoRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import java.util.Optional;

@Component
public class UserInfoUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    UserInfoRepository repository;
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Optional<UserInfo> userInfo = repository.findByName(userName);
        return userInfo.map(UserInfoUserDetails::new)
                .orElseThrow(()-> new UsernameNotFoundException("user not found " + userName));
    }
}
```

Tried making all kinds of changes to the filter. Did Decoding and Encoding too. I dont want to go with @PreAuthorize annotation for roles as it wont be feasible for too many apis.

Comment: using jwts as sessions is a security risk, thats why there is no implementation of it in spring security. Also several things are deprecated in this code. This entire implementation is bad practice. Please instead read and follow the spring security documentation on how to implement proper authentication, using either cookies or oauth2. Whatever blog post you have followed has clearly no idea how security works.

Comment: @Toerktumlare thanks for letting me know. Ofcourse i am trying the spring security for the first time which is why i have hit the roadblock. Can you guide me in a proper direction to implement authorization and authentication in my application? Again, Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Stack overflow is a Q&A site, if you are a beginner i suggest you start out with the officiell documentation. We cant teach you spring security basics, thats what the docs are for. You have to do the work, if you have questions about the docs that is not clear feel free to ask here on SO